# How to set the value of changes?

Tags: jquery

I need the `model` variable to be =`#myModal` when used click on element with the id myBtn.

```
window.onclick=function(e){
    var elem = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
    var model;
    switch(elem.id) {
        case "myBtn": 
            $("#myModal").show("display","block");
            model = model + `#myModal`;
            break;
        case "myBtn_2":
            $("#myModal_2").show("display","block");
            break;
        default:
            alert(model)
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean = #myModal when myBtn clicked?

Comment: @IvnH , Yes, when I press `myBtn`, `model = #myModal` .

Comment: Replace `var model` with `var model = ''`

Comment: @IvnH , then the value of the variable `model = " "`, so it is written in `alert`

Comment: Check the answer of @Grant Miller. This is a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method:

```
$( '#myBtn' ).click( function ()
{
    model = '#myModal';
});
```